# How to hide/remove geometry column?

Tags: r

I would like to hide (or remove) geometry column from sf data frame. I know that there is a function `st_drop_geometry` but unfortunately it converts sf object back to `data.frame` and I don't want that. I want to drop geometry column and still have `sf` data frame. Is it possible? I tried with `select(-geometry)` but it doesn't help.

Here is short working example:

```
  data_all <- quakes %>%
    dplyr::select(depth, mag, stations, lat, long) %>% 
    sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat"), crs = 4326) %>% 
    dplyr::select(-geometry)
```

Comment: which library does `quakes` come from?

Comment: and an `sf` object without a geometry columns is just a `data.frame`. And it doesn't make sense to have an `sf` object without an `sfc` column.

Comment: You can _force_ it, with `attr( your_df, "class" ) <- c("sf", "data.frame")`, but you'll run in to errors quite quickly

Comment: I think I solved it, because I use this sf data frame as a source to my `reactable` table where I hide geometry column using attribute `show` of `colDef()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise OP's own comments for other people who are new to `sf` objects and want to remove `geometry` from a data frame or tibble:

###### Method 1

```r
sf::st_drop_geometry(data_all)
```

###### Method 2

```r
attr(data_all, "class") <- "data.frame"
attr(data_all, "sf_column") <- NULL
```